# Travelling from England to Northern Ireland via Ireland

Tags: covid-19, ireland, common-travel-area, northern-ireland

Our trip to Northern Ireland got cancelled last year due to lockdowns but we have a credit for the ferry crossing that I'm tentatively looking at rebooking.

Our journey plan is this:

- Leave home in England (my partner and I are both British)
- Drive through Wales
- Get the ferry from Holyhead to Dublin
- Drive up to Northern Ireland immediately from the ferry to stay in a holiday cottage
- Stay from Thursday and leave on Monday
- Drive back from NI to Dublin ferry port
- Get the ferry back from Dublin to Holyhead
- Drive home from Holyhead

This would be our first ever trip to NI. I can get my head around all the stuff about only meeting friends outside, etc. etc., and I know under current rules that we're allowed to travel anywhere in the UK, but what I can't get my head around is how the trip would be affected by the couple of hours in Ireland.

Edit: to address some comments, our booking credit is with Irish Ferries so unfortunately Holyhead->Dublin or Pembroke->Rosslare are our only choices of route.

The IE government website has information about entering Ireland during the pandemic: https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/b4020-travelling-to-ireland-during-the-covid-19-pandemic/

The NI government website also has information about travelling during the pandemic: https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/coronavirus-covid-19-travelling-within-common-travel-area

The UK government website has this information: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/covid-19-coronavirus-restrictions-what-you-can-and-cannot-do

But despite reading all of these pages, I still can't work out:

- If our trip is viable (it's not possible to do a long weekend in NI if we'd have to quarantine for 10 days in an Irish hotel beforehand!)
- What paperwork / tests we have to do and when (it's not possible to take a test 2 days before entering the UK if we've only been out of the UK for 3 hours)

We wouldn't be stopping in Ireland, purely transiting through in our car. The total length of the trip would be 5 days, with only a couple of hours driving in Ireland on day 1 and day 5.

So my question is, what are the practicalities of taking a long weekend trip to Northern Ireland from England, via Wales/Ireland?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might need to raise a second question if I can't work out what paperwork the dog needs to make this trip now that his pet passport no longer seems valid thanks to Brexit.

Comment: If you take the [Cairnryan (Stranraer) to Belfast ferry](https://www.stenaline.co.uk/routes/cairnryan-belfast) you won't need any time in the republic. You have to go to Scotland instead of Wales.

Comment: Adding to @WeatherVane's comment, I can't speak to the practicalities of going through Ireland, but agree that being able to go direct to Belfast or Larne sounds like it would avoid a lot of the issues. There is a Belfast-Liverpool ferry (Stena Line from Birkenhead) - should be easier than getting to Stranraer (or indeed to Holyhead!) from most parts of England.

Comment: [Irish Ferries](https://www.irishferries.com/uk-en/frequently-asked-questions/travel-vouchers/transfer-voucher/) say "Travel Vouchers are not transferable. They can only be used on bookings made on the irishferries.com account of the recipient identified at time of purchase." That implies you can use it on another route. Can't find anything from Stena.

Comment: Thank you for this - I've added an edit to the post. Unfortunately our ferry credit is with Irish Ferries so we only have a choice of their routes - Holyhead->Dublin (our preferred choice) and Pembroke->Rosslare (wrong end of Ireland). If only I'd had the foresight to book the scotland->NI ferry to begin with!

Comment: Like it or not, you're entering Ireland, and their rules apply. My understanding isn't sufficient for an answer, and may be out of date, but I think entering for a holiday is banned, not just subject to quarantine. That's what you're doing, even if you're not sleeping there.

Comment: There are also ferries from Liverpool (Birkenhead) to Belfast. They are run by StennaLine, and it's an 8-hour crossing. It's probably quicker than driving up to Stranraer / Cairnryan and taking the ferry from there.  https://www.stenaline.co.uk/routes/liverpool-belfast

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH-UK ! Looks like I might have to wait until later in the year then when (hopefully) they'll remove some restrictions. Fortunately our ferry voucher is valid until December 31st.

Comment: Good luck @Rae - keep checking the Irish rules.  They should extend validity if you can't use it, but whether they will is another matter

Comment: If anyone comes across this question in the future and is desperate to know what happened, we successfully made the trip at the end of August with no quarantine or testing needed. We're double-jabbed and the rules at the time are that double-jabbed people can enter Ireland from the UK without needing to test/quarantine. The guy at the border control literally said "Where are you from? Are you double-jabbed? Have you filled in The Form? Have a nice stay." and that was it. No checks coming back into Wales from Dublin.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.